# Checking if a template is loaded completely - Aria Templates

Tags: javascript, ariatemplates

I am loading a template in Aria using the following :

```
  Aria.loadTemplate({
    classpath : test,
    div : "thecontainer",


});
```

Can someone tell me how to attach a  callback to this function.This should tell me if a template load is complete or noe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response,i did refer to that and following is my final answer  :

You can provide a callback to the loadTemplate method, which will tell you when the template is loaded and whether an error was raised. However this may not tell you about all the problems, c.f. documentation.

Ex:

```
Aria.loadTemplate({
    classpath : "thetemp",
    div : "thecontainer"
}, {fn: this.myTemplateLoaded, scope: this});

//...

myTemplateLoaded: function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
    //success
  } else {
    //error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing to the function only one parameter, a `cfg` object. You can pass the callback as the second parameter to `Aria.loadTemplate`.

See the source code:
https://github.com/ariatemplates/ariatemplates/blob/v1.4.6/src/aria/Aria.js#L1379

> **@param {aria.core.JsObject.Callback}** callback which will be called
>   when the template is loaded or if there is an error.
>
> The first
>   parameter of the callback is a JSON object with the following
>   properties:
>
> **{ success : {Boolean} true if the template was displayed, false
>   otherwise }**
>
> Note that the callback is called when the template is loaded, but
>   ***sub-templates may still be waiting to be loaded*** (showing a loading
>   indicator). Note that success==true means that the template was
>   displayed, but there may be errors inside some widgets or
>   sub-templates.